# The meaning of "nodding to the plains"

Tags: meaning

For some little time he leaned on the tomb thinking of this dead man of his own blood, and of the house in Devonshire; then, **nodding to the plains**: “Yes; it’s a big work all of it even my little share. He must have been worth knowing. . . . Bukta, where are my people?”

This is from "The Tomb of His Ancestors" by Rudyard Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/TheDaysWork/ancestors.html

I can't understand the meaning of....
nodding to the plains
Does it simply mean "nodding to the plain fields" or "nodding while looking at the plain fields"?

I am glad if someone would kindly teach  me.

Answer (score 2):

[Plains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain) is being used as a noun here, meaning wide flat lands, not the adjective "plain." The phrase "nodding to" suggests that he's using his nodding motion to gesture in the direction of the plains.

Comment: See for instance the North American "Great Plains", the mostly flat grassland between the Mississippi River and the Rocky Mountains.

Comment: Andy, thank you very much for your comment.